# Highcharts: create scatter chart with grouped categories in the x-axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts v4.1.7 and I'm trying to make a scatter-chart with categories grouped by string on the x-axis, and a linear variable on the y-axis.

I thought from [reading the Highcharts docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories) that I would be able to do this by setting `xAxis.type` to `category` and adding a `name` property to my data.

However, that doesn't seem to work - instead the x-axis seems to be set to the index of each data point.

This is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emg76wsa/1/

I want all the `Jan` points to be grouped vertically above the `Jan` label on the x-axis. How can I do this?

Comment: This shows the output I want, but I'm hoping there's a less manual way to achieve it: http://jsfiddle.net/emg76wsa/2/

Comment: Highcharts don't group points based on the same name. By default, if you don't provide `x` value for points, then each point will receive `x += 1`. So, as you noticed, you need to set `x` value for each of the points.